# Stack corruption, unexpected jumps in backtrace

Tags: c++, multithreading, stack

For the sake of NDA I may not be able to paste any code here for this question.

The software I work upon is in c++. In which we use a lot of STL maps, vectors and other standard c++ features, like inheritance and others.

Recently I have been observing a SIGSEGV occur in the software. It is occurring very consistently.

The backtrace is confusing. There are many threads(related to this software) running in the system. The backtrace starts from a thread say THREAD1. It shows us that it is executing some functions in THREAD1, and it proceeds along and suddenly it jumps to THREAD2(which is running in the system), and it starts executing somewhere in the middle it and not from the beginning of that thread instance. It now takes two or three steps more, and then goes for a sigsegv. The threads THREAD1 and THREAD2 are always the same threads.

I have tried to make sure all the checked in code is proper and got them reviewed by many people.

My questions are as follows,

1. **Are such jumps possible?** If yes, what could be the root causes?
2. Are there any debugging steps I can take to find out what is happening with those threads?

Comment: What do you mean "suddenly it jumps"?  The backtrace is just a list of nested function calls; how do you infer threads from that?

Comment: You should add a c++ tag

Comment: Such jumps are possible if a coroutine jump occurs, or if thread2 preempts thread1.

Comment: What backtrace are you looking at? If it's just the call frame stack in a core file, it is thread-specific and cannot jump threads. If you're stepping through a running program, the debugger is probably switching threads due to pre-emption as wallyk suggests.

Comment: "suddenly it jumps" is literally the same. It is just transferring the control from this location to another location in code. Using the elf file, we are able to trace the function calls to different threads, using unix's addr2line command.

Comment: To Useless, no we are not using a debugger. It is a normal code running.

Comment: To further clarify the question for _wallyk_, i will use a small example.
thread1-> func11-> func12-> func13-> func14...
thread2-> func21-> func22-> func23-> func24...

let us say these are the functions associated with each thread context. The functions of thread1 can never be called from thread2, i.e. func13 can never be called from thread2, and neither func23 can be called from thread1. In my case I am able to see the functions func13 and func14 being called from thread2's context. There is absolutely no path from thread2 to these functions, but still I am able to see this jump in the trace